# Python class naming: nested classes or composed names?

Tags: design, object-oriented, python, naming, class-design

I encountered a scenario where I cannot decide on which is the best (or worst) naming strategy. The context is the following: a bracket (as in a tournament) made up of nodes, where is node is made up of two abstract elements which can be a seeded player, a bye, or a reference to another node.

We clearly see a hierarchy of inclusion, conceptually speaking:

```
Bracket > Node > Element = Seed, Bye, Reference
```

I cannot decide whether name them with composed names and declare each class at the same level (no nesting):

```
class Bracket:
    pass

class BracketNode:
    pass

class BracketNodeElement:
    pass

class BracketNodeElementSeed(BracketNodeElement):
    pass

class BracketNodeElementBye(BracketNodeElement):
    pass

class BracketNodeElementReference(BracketNodeElement):
    pass
```

Or wheter be a bit more DRY with the names but making the name arguably uglier:

```
class Bracket:
    class Node:
        class Element:
           pass

        class Seed(Element):
           pass

        class Bye(Element):
           pass

        class Reference(Element):
           pass
```

Accessing a seed or a bye must be expressed this way: `Bracket.Node.Seed` and `Bracket.Node.Bye`.

What is the usual way to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option C: simpler is better. Make each class at the global level, and remove the prefix:

```
class Bracket:
    pass

class Node:
    pass

class Element:
    pass

class Seed(Element):
    pass

class Bye(Element):
    pass

class Reference(Element):
    pass
```

The fact that these all exist in a module gives you the namespacing you need without having to have large, cumbersome class names. For example, assuming you've put these in a file named `tournament.py`, then from anywhere else you would use `tournament.Bracket`, `tournament.Node`, etc.

Comment: Should BracketNodeElement say 'Element'?

Comment: @Brandin: yes. Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed the answer.